# Problema al escribir respuesta de HTTP (Android, java)

Tags: java, android, http

Tengo un problema a la hora de escribir en una variable la respuesta **(formato JSON)** de una petición `HTTP` realizada con `Volley`.
Tengo una objeto `JSONCONTAINER` global **(clase programada por mi, simplemente contiene 3 JSONObjects)** en la que deseo escribir 3 JSON procedentes de 3 peticiones `HTTP` a `google places`:

```
public JsonContainer JSONCONTAINER = new JsonContainer(new JSONObject(),new JSONObject(),new JSONObject());
```

Para hacer la segunda y la tercera petición necesito un **token** que me devuelven la primera y segunda, respectivamente. Para eso llamo a una función donde obtengo el primer `JSON` a la que le paso la `url` por parámetro:

```
private void getFirstPage(String url){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                JSONCONTAINER.setJson1(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO: Handle error
                print("ERROR");
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Bueno, el caso es que para llamar a esa función desde la interfaz utilizo un simple botón. La primera vez que clico en el botón no pasa nada, pero la segunda vez si lo escribe correctamente.  ¿A que se debe esto?
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

---

**EDIT:** Añado el codigo del listener del botón:

```
btnTodosBancos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Map<String, String> listaBancos = checkPreferences();
            String banco1 = listaBancos.get("banco1");
            String banco2 = listaBancos.get("banco2");
            String banco3 = listaBancos.get("banco3");

            if(banco1 != null || banco2 != null || banco3 != null){
                geoLocate(banco1,banco2,banco3);
            }
        }
    });
```

---

Y el código de la función a la que se llama desde ese botón

```
public void geoLocate(final String banco1, final String banco2, final String banco3){
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.radioSpinner);
    int radius = (int) spinner.getSelectedItem();
    LatLng latLng = getCurrentLocation();

    StringBuilder googleURL = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googleURL.append("location=" + latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude);
    googleURL.append("&radius=" + radius);
    if(banco1 != null){
        googleURL.append("&name=" + banco1.toLowerCase());
    }
    if(banco2 != null){
        if(banco1!=null){
            googleURL.append("|" + banco2.toLowerCase());
        } else {
            googleURL.append("&name=" + banco2.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    if(banco3 != null){
        if(banco1!=null || banco2!=null){
            googleURL.append("|" + banco3.toLowerCase());
        } else {
            googleURL.append("&name=" + banco3.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    googleURL.append("&type=" + "bank");
    googleURL.append("&key=" + APIKEY);

    String url = googleURL.toString();
    getFirstPage(url);
    getSecondPage(JSONCONTAINER.getJson1(),url);
    getThirdPage(JSONCONTAINER.getJson2(),url);
}
```

No pongo el código de `getSecondPAge()` y `getThirdPage()` ya que por el momento son irrelevantes.

Comment: Debes poner en la pregunta el código de los botones, para ver cómo se relacionan los clicks de estos con la petición Volley. Por otra parte es muy raro lo que explicas: tener que pedir el token primero para luego hacer las peticiones ¿? ¿Por qué no mandas la petición y el token juntos y te evitas tantas llamadas?

Comment: Hola, he añadido el código del listener. Diría que eso está correcto, sospecho que el mal funcionamiento se puede deber a algo relacionado con la asincroneidad del Response.Listener. Con respecto a lo de las peticiones: La api de Google places devuelve un JSON con un máximo de 20 resultados. En caso de que haya más de 20 resultados te devuelve en ese mismo objeto JSON un token que tienes que añadir a la peticion HTTP para obtener la segunda página, y de igual manera con la tercera. El límite de páginas que devuelve es 3.

Comment: Te recomiendo que elimines tu API KEY del código que has compartido. Evita publicar información sensible aquí. Ahora vamos a revisar...

Comment: Depura lo que ocurre en el `onResponse`, imprimiendo la variable `response` o dinos si imprime error. En ese caso, deberías imprimir el error en vez de un simple `print("ERROR");`

Comment: Eso lo he comprobado y la variable onResponse contiene el JSON correcto. Antes lo que hacía era coger ese JSON y pasarlo a una segunda actividad donde lo parseaba y lo mostraba en un mapa, y funcionaba perfectamente.El problema empezó al intentar sacar ese token del prmer json para hacer una segunda petición. Necesito guardarlo en alguna variable para hacer la petición, pero como la respuesta está dentro de una inner class no me permite guardarlo en una variable de la función getFirstPage, por eso tuve que recurrir a crear un objeto final y guardarlo en una de las variables de ese objeto.e

Comment: Yo no alcanzo a comprender la lógica que estás implementando, la cual, aunque logres hacer que funcione, es muy precaria, sobre todo porque las peticiones `Volley` son asíncronas. Me parece un error tratar de hacer tres peticiones una tras otra. Generalmente las APIs tiene funciones de *paginación*  por llamarlo de algún modo, donde puedes moverte de un grupo de contenido al siguiente (quizá deberías explorar esa posibilidad) de modo que puedas programar un código que te permita moverte entre los resultados como pasar de página...

Comment: ... Si eso no es posible (lo cual dudo, más tratándose de Google), entonces puedes explorar la posibilidad de añadir las tres peticiones a la cola de Volley o algo así. Me parece que fragmentar las peticiones es un tremendo lío y que la App en un contexto concurrente hará crash tarde o temprano.

Comment: O bien puedes enlazar las peticiones así: `primeraPeticion()` -> desde el `onResponse()` de la 1ª lanzar `segundaPeticion()` y desde el `onResponse()` de la 2ª lanzar `terceraPeticion()`.

Comment: Está bien, miraré más en profundidad la app de Google Places a ver si consigo hacer lo que me dices. El problema de la asincroneidad con las peticiones Volley ya lo había pensado pero no conocía otra manera de hacerlo. En último caso haré lo que me dices de enlazar las peticiones. Muchas gracias por la ayuda y tu paciencia. Un saludo :)

Comment: De nada. Lo mejor es que revises la documentación de Google, para ver lo que ellos recomiendan para estos casos. En otras APIs se explica claramente cómo hacer cuando se trata de respuestas paginadas, imagino que para este caso no será menos. Revisa allí, así optarás por la opción más óptima, sin tener que intentar reinventar la rueda. Cualquier cosa, tienes este sitio para plantear las dudas, problemas, errores. Quizá @jorgesys pueda dar alguna pincelada sobre esto, él tiene mucha experiencia en Android. Saludos.